# Why does this inequality hold true for any norm $\|a\| \|b\| \lesssim \delta \|a \|^2 + \delta^{-1} \|b\|^2 $ for $ \forall \delta >0$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

$\|a\| \|b\| \lesssim \delta \|a \|^2 + \delta^{-1} \|b\|^2 $
for any $\delta >0$.

Is this true for any kind of norm? Can you show me why?

Answer (score 5):

Sure, it's the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means). It has actually nothing to do with the underlying norm, or any norm for that matter.

Consider $\alpha\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \sqrt{\delta}\lVert a\rVert$ and $\beta\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \sqrt{\delta^{-1}}\lVert b\rVert$. Then, the AM-GM inequality yields
$$
\lVert a\rVert\lVert b\rVert = \alpha\beta \leq \frac{\alpha^2+\beta^2}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\delta\lVert a\rVert^2 + \delta^{-1}\lVert b\rVert^2\right)
$$

Comment: When I say it has nothing to do with any norm: you can replace $\lVert a\rVert$ and $\lVert b\rVert$ by any two reals, the inequality will hold and be proven the same way.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
\|a\|\|b\|&=(\delta^{1/2})\|a\|(\delta^{-1/2})\|b\|\\
&=\|\delta^{1/2}a\|\|\delta^{-1/2}b\|\\
&\leq2^{-1}(\|\delta^{1/2}a\|^{2}+\|\delta^{-1/2}b\|^{2})\\
&=2^{-1}(\delta\|a\|+\delta^{-1}\|b\|^{2}).
\end{align*}

Comment: And there is no need to absorb the $\delta^{1/2}$ or $\delta^{-1/2}$ into the norm, just Arithmetic-Geometric inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\;\delta^2 \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2 \color{red}{- 2\delta\|a\|\|b\| + 2\delta\|a\|\|b\|} = \big(\delta\|a\|-\|b\|\big)^2 + 2\delta\|a\|\|b\| \ge 2\delta\|a\|\|b\|\,$.